# Jquery - Muliple clicks causing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The issue I face is that when I click on `#apple1` multiple times, the accordion panel i.e. `appleInfo1` moves up and down repeatedly until it has matched up with how many times I have initially clicked the button.

```
$('#appleInfo1').hide().promise().done(function(){
    $('#apple1').click(function(){
        $('#appleInfo1').slideToggle(1000);
        $('#intelInfo1, #ibmInfo1, #amdInfo1').slideUp(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: As an aside, consider using a class rather than 3 id selectors.

Comment: Also, I'd consider using javascript only for toggling a class, and style and animate the position with CSS transitions - it's a nicer separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `stop()` any ongoing animations when you click again.
Also, the promise makes little sense when not passing in a duration to `hide()`

```
var apple = $('#appleInfo1').hide()

$('#apple1').click(function(){
    apple.stop(true,true).slideToggle(1000);
    $('#intelInfo1, #ibmInfo1, #amdInfo1').stop(true,true).slideUp(1000);
});
```